# netplan with vlan dhcp does not assign address

Tags: dhcp, netplan

I have a device with two physical network interfaces, enp2s0 and enp3s0!

All communication should be assigt to vlans.

The device runs ubuntu and is a host for a KVM system, therefor also a bridge is defined.

```
network:
        version: 2
        renderer: networkd
        ethernets:
                enp2s0:
                        # MAC: 00:01:2e:93:a9:88
                        dhcp4: false
                        dhcp6: false
                        wakeonlan: true
                enp3s0:
                        # MAC: 00:01:2e:93:a9:89
                        dhcp4: false
                        dhcp6: false
                        wakeonlan: true
        bridges:
                br0:
                        # MAC: ca:b7:f8:5e:99:a4
                        dhcp4: false
                        dhcp6: false
                        interfaces: [enp3s0.108]
        vlans:
                enp2s0.110:
                        # MAC: 00:01:2e:93:a9:88
                        id: 110
                        link: enp2s0
                        dhcp4: true
                        dhcp4-overrides:
                                send-hostname: true
                                route-metric: 100
                                use-routes: false
                        dhcp6: true
                        dhcp6-overrides:
                                send-hostname: true
                                route-metric: 100
                                use-routes: false
                        accept-ra: true
                        routes:
                                - to: default
                                  via: 192.168.110.1
                                  metric: 100
                                - to: default
                                  via: "fe80::2a0:57ff:fe54:ec96"
                                  metric: 100
                                  table: 100
                        routing-policy:
                                - from: 192.168.110.8/24
                enp3s0.108:
                        # MAC: 00:01:2e:93:a9:89
                        id: 108
                        link: enp3s0
                        dhcp4: true
                        dhcp4-overrides:
                                hostname: f42252v8
                                use-routes: false
                        dhcp6: true
                        dhcp6-overrides:
                                hostname: f42252v8
                                use-routes: false
                        accept-ra: true
                        routes:
                                - to: default
                                  via: 192.168.108.1
                                  metric: 200
                                  table: 200
                                - to: default
                                  via: "fe80::2a0:57ff:fe54:ec96"
                                  metric: 200
                                  table: 200
                        routing-policy:
                                - from: 192.168.108.8/24
```

For some reason, for enp3s0.108 there is no ip-address assigned.

```
netplan status --all
WARNING:root:Unknown device type: vlan
WARNING:root:Unknown device type: vlan
WARNING:root:Unknown device type: vlan
WARNING:root:Unknown device type: vlan
WARNING:root:Unknown device type: vlan
WARNING:root:Unknown device type: vlan
     Online state: online
    DNS Addresses: 127.0.0.1

●  1: lo ethernet UNKNOWN/UP (unmanaged)
      MAC Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00
        Addresses: 127.0.0.1/8
                   ::1/128
           Routes: ::1 metric 256

●  2: enp2s0 ethernet UP (networkd: enp2s0)
      MAC Address: 00:01:2e:93:a9:88 (Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.)
        Addresses: fe80::201:2eff:fe93:a988/64 (link)
           Routes: fe80::/64 metric 256

●  3: enp3s0 ethernet UP (networkd: enp3s0)
      MAC Address: 00:01:2e:93:a9:89 (Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.)

●  4: wlp1s0 wifi/"(null)" DOWN (unmanaged)
      MAC Address: 48:89:e7:db:ec:d2 (Intel Corporation)

●  5: br0 bridge UP (networkd: br0)
      MAC Address: ca:b7:f8:5e:99:a4
        Addresses: fe80::c8b7:f8ff:fe5e:99a4/64 (link)
           Routes: ...:1302::/64 metric 1024 (ra)
                   ...:1300::/56 via fe80::2a0:57ff:fe54:ec96 metric 1024 (ra)
                   fe80::/64 metric 256
                   default via fe80::2a0:57ff:fe54:ec96 metric 1024 (ra)

●  6: enp2s0.110 other UP (networkd: enp2s0.110)
      MAC Address: 00:01:2e:93:a9:88
        Addresses: 192.168.110.8/24 (dhcp)
                   ...:1301::8/128
                   fe80::201:2eff:fe93:a988/64 (link)
    DNS Addresses: 192.168.110.1
                   192.168.110.8
                   fe80::2a0:57ff:fe54:ec96
       DNS Search: averlon.loc
           Routes: default via 192.168.110.1 metric 100 (static)
                   192.168.110.0/24 from 192.168.110.8 metric 100 (link)
                   192.168.110.1 from 192.168.110.8 metric 100 (dhcp, link)
                   192.168.110.8 from 192.168.110.8 metric 100 (dhcp, host)
                   ...:1301::/64 metric 100 (ra)
                   ...:1300::/56 via fe80::2a0:57ff:fe54:ec96 metric 100 (ra)
                   fe80::/64 metric 256
                   default via fe80::2a0:57ff:fe54:ec96 metric 100 (ra)

●  7: enp3s0.108 other UP (networkd: enp3s0.108)
      MAC Address: 00:01:2e:93:a9:89

● 10: vnet2 ethernet UNKNOWN/UP (unmanaged)
      MAC Address: fe:54:00:a4:86:c4
        Addresses: fe80::fc54:ff:fea4:86c4/64 (link)
           Routes: fe80::/64 metric 256
```

I appreciate any hint what could be set wrong.

Update: When I look at my DHCP-Server, an ip-address is assigned to MAC Address: 00:01:2e:93:a9:89 (means enp3s0.108)

By the way, I don't know wher the error message from netplan comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add an interface to a bridge, you normally want to do the IP configuration on the bridge interface, not the underlying physical interface (or in this case, vlan).  The nature of a bridge is that there is only one IP layer (layer 3) configuration for all interfaces in the bridge.

For debugging purposes, you may want to check whether you get a DHCP address on the vlan interface when NOT adding it to a bridge.

Comment: yes, I get an ip-address on the vlan if I NOT add it to the bridge. I will change the configuration and test again.